# replacing inline javascript with jquery listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="handleViewClick(event)" id="heart" class="next" >
    <img src="../images/Love_Heart_SVG1.svg"/>
  </a>
```

which I would like to replace with something like:

```
    $('#heart','nHeart').on('click', function(e){
        handleViewClick(e);
    });
```

In the document ready function.  Problem is, the inline works, the other doesn't.  I am using bootstrap v4.

Can someone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: You must be including your JS code before the HTML content. Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function() {});` Please show some code.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet/demo showing how you've set up the code that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems to it, first wrap your code inside the following block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Also, doing this `$('#heart','nHeart')` means you want to access a element with id `heart` which should be inside an HTML element `nHeart` in the DOM. If this is not the case then change your code to `$('#heart')`.

Or, else if you can register a global listener in th following way:

```
$(document).on('click', '#heart', function(e) {
    handleViewClick(e);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#heart').on('click', function(e){
        handleViewClick(e);
    });
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation alogn with your code :)

Comment: haha, you had extra items jquery selector if you remove this your code will work :)

Answer (score -1):

Try below

```
  $(function(){
    $('#heart').click(function(e){
    handleViewClick(e);
     });

 });
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation alogn with your code :)